# Executing linux commands from inside java program

Tags: java, shell, command-line

I am trying to create a GUI using java swing. From there I have to run linux system commands. I tried using exec(). But the exec() function is unable to parse the string if it contains single quotes. The code which I have used is as follows-

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cpabe-enc pub_key message.txt '( it_department or ( marketing and manager ) )'")
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
```

But I am getting error when I run the program as--syntax error at `"'("`.

The same command runs when I write

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cpabe-enc pub_key message.txt default")
```

Please help. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split up the parameters into an array instead, one string for each argument, and use the exec-method that takes as `String[]` instead, that generally works better for arguments.
Somethign along the lines of:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cpabe-enc", "pub_key", "message.txt", "( it_department or ( marketing and manager ) )"});
```

or whatever what your exact parameters are.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the runtime does not interpret the '(...)' as a single parameter like you intend.

Try using ProcessBuilder instead:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

I recently got this kind of problem solved. I was using javaFX to call shell scripts on button click .. which is very much similar to your swing application scenario...

Here are the links hope it might help you...

[How to code in java to run unix shell script which use rSync internally in windows environment using cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840970/how-to-code-in-java-to-run-unix-shell-script-which-use-rsync-internally-in-windo)

[Getting error in calling shell script in windows environment using java code and cygwin...!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852202/getting-error-in-calling-shell-script-in-windows-environment-using-java-code-and)

Happy coding... :)